# How to parse only the day using SimpleDateFormat

Tags: java, parsing, simpledateformat

I'd like to parse given date by user but with a specific format : the day name of the week.

So far, here's what I did :

```
SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("E", Locale.ENGLISH);

try {
    Date date = format.parse ("Friday");
    Calendar calendar = format.getCalendar();
    calendar.add(Calendar.WEEK_OF_YEAR, 1);
    return calendar.getTime();
}
catch (ParseException pe) {
    return null;
}
```

But this returns me :

```
2 janv. 1970 00:00:00
```

I'd like it to return me the future friday (in our timelapse, `4 nov. 2011`)

How can I do ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Parse just the day, put that into a `Calendar` so that you can find the day of the week, then create *another* calendar based on the current date so that you can set the day of week:

```
currentCalendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK,
                    parsedCalendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK));
```

Note that that won't necessarily put it into the future - it'll set the day *within the current week*. So you may want to add a week afterwards, if you want to ensure that it's really in the future:

```
// Assume we've already done all the parsing
int dayOfWeek = parsedCalendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK);

long now = System.currentTimeMillis();
Calendar currentCalendar = Calendar.getInstance();
currentCalendar.setTimeInMillis(now);
currentCalendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK, dayOfWeek);
if (currentCalendar.getTimeInMillis() < now) {
    currentCalendar.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 7);
}
```

(You should check what behaviour you want if the current day of week is the same as the parsed one...)

As an aside, I'd personally recommend using [Joda Time](http://joda-time.sf.net) for all serious date and time work in Java. It's a much nicer API.

Comment: if OP wants future day then he can check the current day against the passed day and if its passed for this week then add 1 to week .

Comment: @JigarJoshi: Yes, that's what I meant. I'll clarify my comment.

Comment: Could you post an example on how would you do with JodaTime? I don't see how I can do that. Thanks :)

Comment: @cx42net: Which bit of it is giving you problems in Joda Time? `LocalDate.withDayOfWeek` and `LocalDate.plusWeeks` would be the relevant calls after parsing... are you having problems in the parsing itself?

Comment: Well it seems to work with Calendar, do I need to use JodaTime then? (I never used it, that's why I don't know how to proceed)

Comment: @cx42net: You don't *need* to - but it's a nicer API in general.

Comment: Ok thanks for the help, I added a new question, if you want to play ;) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7965645/add-a-date-to-now-by-parsing-the-input

Answer (score 3):

Get a `Calendar.getInstance()` and simpyl set the `DAY_OF_WEEK` to the value of the `format.getCalendar()`. You'd need to make a check if the current date of week is after Friday. In that case - increment the week.

Comment: that won't set future Friday always