# Add a date to now by parsing the input

Tags: java, parsing, date

I'm having an hard time trying to parse date in the future, and I would apreciate some help!

Here's the thing, I'd like to add a parsed date to the current date (to have it in the future). The problem is that I can have many kind of date format, like :

- dd
- MM-dd
- yyyy-MM-dd

So if the user set something like `5`, the returned date will be (in our timelapse) `2011-11-05`.
If he set `02-14`, it will be `2012-02-14`.

But suppose we are the `4th of november`, and the user set `11-03`, it will be `2012-11-03` and not `2011-11-03` since it's past.

I tried to play with Calendar, Date, SimpleFormat, but I cannot make it work.

My parsers (using SimpleDateFormat) are working though.

Could you help me archieve this? I'm not asking for a complete code, just something that would set me on the right track!

thanks! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have had very good experience with jodatime - http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/. Checkout the Dateformatters in that.

It has a very extensive API and lets you do things like add and subtract dates - taking into account timezones and daylight saving etc.

Comment: I tried to use the DateFormatters, I can match the dates in string using them, but how can I have it to be in the current date + what is given ? (if just day is given, set the month & year to current) ?

Comment: I don't think there is anything built in for this. But you can do something like this: foo = new DateTime(); new DateTime(foo.getYear, foo.getMonth, userInputDay, 0, 0, 0);

Comment: Using Joda and adding time instead of just creating it with the format is the way to do.

Answer (score 2):

Since you have fixed list of acceptable input date format, set the lenient field of `dateFormat` to `false` and check to see if one of them satisfy your work done or if exception is raised go for next pattern

```
dateFormat  = new SimpleDateFormat(PATTERN_ONE);
dateFOrmat.setLenient(false);
dateFormat.parse(INPUT_STRING);
// if an exception is caughtm try with next pattern
```

Comment: You say Lenient:true in your description, but set it to false in your code. Which one should I trust ? ;)

Comment: Well your tip did help me for an other problem :)